# bind drop down to grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a one drop down list containing the list of items. each item is further connecting to different table. 
there is gridview that show the selected table by selecetd item in drop down list.
how is it possible?
that to show the selected table f

Comment: the data source is from table. i make a sql data source and make a connection string. but i don't know how to bind the selected value from drop down to grid view.

Comment: Where do your tables reside ? (a dataset perhapse? )

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.DataSource = tableCollection[dropDownList.SelectedValue];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this for your dropdown in your gridview.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Condition" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="40px>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConditions" runat="server" >  
            </asp:DropDownList>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Under your grid "RowDataBound" event, you will bind your dropdown in code behind using dropdown id.

```
DropDownList ddlConditions2 = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlConditions") as DropDownList);
                DataTable dt = _reader.GetDataTableByCommandFromStoredProc("getYourDropdownData");
                ddlConditions2.DataSource = dt;
                ddlConditions2.DataTextField = "ConditionName";
                ddlConditions2.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlConditions2.DataBind();
                ddlConditions2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful.  Please [edit] your answer to provide additional context to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: now bind your dropdown in code hehind using dropdown id as i used in above answer section .